# characteristics for setting color with homekit

Tags: ios, homekit

i'm using https://github.com/etwmc/Personal-HomeKit-HAP- to simulate a homekit compatible device. 
Siri will not accept commands for color, like "change my lamps to blue", responding with "your lights are not responding" while there clearly as no request. I assume its because my characteristics dont match siri's expectations, but which ones _are the correct ones?

```
printf("Initial Accessory\n");
accSet = &AccessorySet::getInstance();
Accessory *lightAcc = new Accessory();
addInfoServiceToAccessory(lightAcc, "Light 1", "ET", "Light", "12345678", &lightIdentify);
accSet->addAccessory(lightAcc);

Service *lightService = new Service(charType_lightBulb);
lightAcc->addService(lightService);

stringCharacteristics *lightServiceName = new stringCharacteristics(charType_serviceName, premission_read, 0);
lightServiceName->setValue("Light");
lightAcc->addCharacteristics(lightService, lightServiceName);

boolCharacteristics *powerState = new boolCharacteristics(charType_on, premission_read|premission_write|premission_notify);
powerState->setValue("true");
powerState->valueChangeFunctionCall = &changeLightState;
lightAcc->addCharacteristics(lightService, powerState);

intCharacteristics *brightnessState = new intCharacteristics(charType_brightness, premission_read|premission_write|premission_notify, 0, 100, 1, unit_percentage);
brightnessState->setValue("50");
brightnessState->valueChangeFunctionCall = &changeLightIntensity;
lightAcc->addCharacteristics(lightService, brightnessState);

intCharacteristics *saturationState= new intCharacteristics(charType_saturation, premission_read|premission_write|premission_notify, 0, 100, 1, unit_percentage);
saturationState->setValue("100");
saturationState->valueChangeFunctionCall = &changeLightSat;
lightAcc->addCharacteristics(lightService, saturationState);

intCharacteristics *hueState= new intCharacteristics(charType_hue, premission_read|premission_write|premission_notify, 0, 360, 1, unit_arcDegree);
hueState->setValue("0");
hueState->valueChangeFunctionCall = &changeLightColor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homekit database is shared and it will accessible to all homekit enabled application install in device as well as **Siri**, but siri only understand the names you have given to Home, accessory, trigger, scene and by characteristic of services and other homekit objects.

Now if you want to change color of any accessory(Light), most probablly it will have **Saturation** ,**Brightness** and **Hue** characteristic.
combination of this 3 characteristic will create a color.

So you can tell siri to change Saturation, Brightness and Hue,

Like
Siri, set desk lamp Hue in Main Hall to 220 (Hue can be 0 to 360)

Here **Main Hall** is name of room (You can change your own),
**desk lamp** is name of accessory
**Hue** is characteristic of **desk lamp's** light service.

and **220** is value of characteristic.
**Hue** is actual color or shade.

Comment: yep. i did expose hue, brightness and saturation, as you can see in my code. They work fine in HomeKitDemo app, but siri doesn't seem to recognize them as color.

Comment: @aep you can use hue, okay! (To change the color)
As "Color" is not a characteristic so siri won't understand it except you create a custom characteristic for color (In this case also you need to manage certain things as format for the characteristic value will not be UIColor, I can be string, float, int32/uint8 etc)